# Using transfrom:scale in CSS displays scroll bars below？

Tags: css

Using transfrom:scale in CSS displays scroll bars below，How can I hide this scroll bar？
`After I used the Animate On Scroll Library, the scroll bar was always at the bottom of my web page, and I really wanted to get rid of it。 Please help me！Thank you very much！` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvqwB.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SwCr.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4SeO.png)